# Format Float to N0 and convert to String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns, two are bit values, and one is a float. I want to combine these values into one column using the following case statement, I need the final column to be a string, so I can have text values representing the Bit values. This works fine, however, I also want to format the float as 'N0' before converting to a string. So a large number is shown as 1,234,567,890.

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN nd = 1 THEN 'ND'
    WHEN nil = 1 THEN 'Nil'
    ELSE LTRIM(STR(FORMAT(position, 'N0'))
END AS position
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure ChkSummary, Line 46 [Batch Start Line 152] 
> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

EDIT:
DBMS SQL Server

As comments suggest ELSE FORMAT(position, 'N0') works.

Comment: Remove the `ltrim(str(`.

Comment: "format the float as 'N0' before converting to a string" doesn't make sense, as soon as you apply `FORMAT` the result *is* a string. When you call `STR` it then tries to implicitly cast it back to float again. You don't need this anyway